# Why is params keyword not contextual?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

The reason I ask is, it's only valid in method parameter declaration, isn't it? I was trying to make a variable inside the function body called "params", but of course this is not a big deal, just wondering the reason MS chose to make it a global keyword and not contextual.

Comment: Not sure on the why part, but if you really want to use this as a variable name in c# preface the variable name with @: int @params = 1;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tvanoffson's answer conjectures that it would be hard to make "params" contextual. It actually wouldn't be that hard. Consider:

```
void M(params x)
```

What we'd do in this case, hypothetically, is first attempt to find a type 'params'. If we could find one, great, we're done. If we couldn't, then we have a bit of a problem. suppose for example instead of x it was

```
void M(params Int32)
```

Clearly that's an error, but what error? Should we assume that Int32 is the parameter name and give the error "you're missing the type"? Should we assume that Int32 is the type and give an error saying that the type has to be an array type, and that you're missing the identifier?  Should we give an error saying that there is no type named 'params'? What is the right thing to do here? Clearly we could figure something out but is not obvious.

It's the error cases that are tricky with contextual keywords; getting the success cases working is actually pretty straightforward.

But really, it's not so much that it is *hard* to make contextual as that making it contextual is not a really big win. Making "set" and "value" contextual was a big win because we assumed that all kinds of people are going to be wanting to make local variables with names like "set" and "value". "params" isn't even an English word, so it seems less likely that anyone is going to want to use it. There's no big benefit to making it contextual, so the cost of the feature is not justified.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was really hoping to read what you had in mind. To me it seems like the valid cases would be 1. Is there a params type available? 2. If not, then there has to be a type in the form of Type[], and followed by an identifier. I am not an expert like you, but do you think this covers all the cases? Also you are right, it's not an English word, just thought it would be useful in some code, instead of writing parameter/(s).

Answer (score 9):

The same could be asked about any other keyword. For example, why isn't "class" contextual since it's only used in class declarations?

To me a keyword is a keyword. I imagine it greatly simplifies the lexical analysis part of compilation to not have to be THAT context aware.

As an aside, you can use the `@` symbol to allow you to declare a variable called 'params' (or any other reserved keyword):

```
var @params = new int[] { 1, 2 };
```

Comment: Thanks but if class was contextual then how would they separate nested class usage? But with params, there just isn't any other place to use it, and seems to be it would be easy to distinguish them, but I am not a compiler maestro like Eric Lippert.

Comment: I think you could try to make 'class' contextual by looking for typical class declaration syntax: [accessibility modifier] class [class name] {}. But I'm not up on the compiler spec enough to know if this is actually feasible.

Comment: Suppose "class" were contextual. Suppose you have "class class{} class get{} class C { public class D { get" -- at this point you do not know whether D is a nested class declaration with a field (or method) of type "get" with the name missing, or whether D is a property of type "class" with the getter body missing. These sorts of situations are obviously contrived, but if we support the feature then we have to come up with sensible errors for *all possible such cases*. That's a lot of analysis, a lot of spec writing and an enormous amount of testing for a feature that benefits hardly anyone.

Comment: Incidentally, when I added classes to VBScript 5 we *did* make "Class" a new reserved word in VBScript, rather than making it contextual. The grammar and semantics of VBScript made it rather difficult to determine when "Class Foo" was an introduction of a class, or a call to the procedure "Class" with argument "Foo". It was vexing to have to add a new reserved word, but the alternatives were determined to be worse.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's exactly what I was thinking with the "class" keyword being contextual.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Lippert has a blog post covering [contextual and reserved keywords](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords.aspx) and their history.  Though it doesn't explicitly explain why params is in the reserved list (it has been since 1.0), it implies that it belongs to the set of reserved words that would be *hard* to make contextual.

Comment: Thanks, that's what reserved words are for? I thought it meant it's reserved for new potential uses in the future?

Comment: @Joan - some may be, but most are *reserved* as in "reserved for this purpose only."

Answer (score 2):

The params keyword does look to be only useful in method parameter declaration, but I actually agree with MS that it wouldn't be a good idea to let keywords be used for instance names, anyway.

Perhaps they are reserving the ability to have something like this in C# 8.0:

```
params Customers = DB.GetCustomerList();
```

Or otherwise allow `params` in a local scope as well.

Comment: But what would that do? To me using it in local scope that you showed wouldn't make much sense, would it? I am not sure. Btw when is C# 8.0 is coming out? :O

Comment: i think around 2017 if my crystal ball is accurate.

Comment: Joan - Good question.  I have no idea what that would do.  In fact, I don't even think that line of code will compile in C# 8.0 due to a syntax error.